# How split a Delphi solution into reusable run-time packages?

Tags: delphi-xe5, bpl

I'm starting with Delphi XE5 and I would like to split my application in one exe and multiple reusable libraries. That means I don't want to split the running *.exe application in DLLs or runtime Packages.

To achieve this, I have seen that in delphi we can create runtime packages and I followed the following steps:

1. I have created a new VCL Forms Application project (EXE project).
2. I have added a new Package project (BPL project) to the project group and I have  modified its project options to set usage options to 'Runtime only' and build control to 'Explicit rebuild'.
3. I have added a dependency betwen the EXE project and the BPL project (EXE project depends on BPL project).
4. Finally I have compiled the BPL project and added the generated DCP file as a runtime package in the EXE project (Project options/Package/Runtime Packages).

But when I add a reference on the EXE project to use a module (moduleX for example) from the BPL project, compiler give me an error like this:

[dcc32 Fatal Error] ModuleX.pas(7): F1026 File not found: 'C:\DDDProject\MyEXEProject\ModuleX.dcu'

If I mark as checked the 'Link with runtime packages' option in the EXE project (MyEXEProject) the solution compiles without errors but I can't run or debug the application.

Please, can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1):

> I don't want to split the running *.exe application in DLLs or runtime Packages.

Runtime Package BPL files **are** DLLs. That is what allows them to be shared amongst multiple EXEs.  They are just normal DLLs with special VCL/FMX handling built in.

When you enable the "Link with runtime packages" option, you are linking the EXE file to your BPL file (or DYLIB or SO file, if compiling for platforms other than Windows), so you MUST distribute the BPL file (and any other BPL files it depends on, like rtl190.bpl and vcl190.bpl) with your EXE file.  So they have to be in the EXE's folder, or at least in the [OS search path](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa297182.aspx), in order for the EXE to run.

When you disable the "Link with runtime packages" option, your package's code is statically linked directly into the EXE file, so you need to make sure the EXE project's search paths include the folder were your package's DCU file(s) are located.

If you want to create a reusable library but not a BPL, then create a **Static Library** (a LIB file) instead of a **Runtime Package**.  You can then add the LIB file to multiple projects as needed.